# Disable Google PageSpeed Service at a current page

Tags: pagespeed

I don't want PageSpeed Service to run on index.php of my wordpress based website. Site is a news website so the mainpage changes every hour however when I linked to PageSpeed Service mainpage does not change (ctrl+f5, shift+f5 dont work). I see news of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set a blacklist of URLs](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/settings#blacklist).

1. Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console
2. Click PageSpeed Service
3. Click COnfigure Rewriters
4. Enter URLs into the blacklist

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I tried but it did not work in my case, it still continue to cache

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the Prioritize Content > Cache HTML option, you can specify the non-cacheable parts (div ids/classes).  This should work in your case, but that particular processor broke too many other important features and I had to disable it altogether.